# How can I use (initialize, manipulate, get output from) mkl handles in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, handle, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am using the Intel Fortran compiler in WSL, with its installation directory `/opt/intel`. I want to use the sparse BLAS functions. [link to intel's documentation of the libaray](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-mkl-sparse-mv).

Here is part of the related code.

```
double complex, allocatable ::  H(:,:),Hvert(:,:),Hstar(:,:)
allocate(H(dimH,dimH),Hvert(dimH,dimH),Hstar(dimH,dimH))

! initialization of Hstar
info = mkl_sparse_z_create_coo(Hstar, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, m**L, m**L, 2**L, ind(1,:), ind(2,:), Hele)

! initialization of empty matrix
ind = 0
info = mkl_sparse_z_create_coo(Hvert, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, m**L, m**L, 0, ind(1,1), ind(2,1), H)

! add A and B to form the final matrix
info = mkl_sparse_z_add(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, Hstar, 1d0, Hvert, H)
```

When I compile it with the following command

```sh
ifort -xHost -parallel full.f90 -o output -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_spblas -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -qopenmp && ./output
```

it gave me the following error, even if I have sourced the libraries

```
source /opt/intel/bin/ifortvars.sh -arch intel64 -platform linux
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform linux
```

```sh
full.f90(146): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MKL_SPARSE_Z_CREATE_COO]
     info = mkl_sparse_z_create_coo(Hvert, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, m**L, m**L, 2**L, ind(1,:), ind(2,:), Hele)
------------^
full.f90(226): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MKL_SPARSE_Z_ADD]
     info = mkl_sparse_z_add(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, Hstar, 1d0, Hvert, H)
------------^
full.f90(240): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MKL_SPARSE_Z_MV]
       info = mkl_sparse_z_mv(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, 1d0, H, SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_HERMITIAN, psi(a,:), 0d0, dummy)
--------------^
compilation aborted for full.f90 (code 1)
```

I think it is caused by my incorrect linking to the related library as well as initializing the matrices as plain allocatable arrays.

What should I do to use these functions?

also, I have no idea what the uppercase variables`SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE` mean. Should I use it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the linking path is correct. You don't need to link -mkl_spblas. Please refer always to the MKL Linker Adviser ( https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor).
I would recommend looking at the existing sparse_z_csrmv.f90 example which shows how to make the call of the similar Sparse BLAS functions. This example has been call CSR but not COO formats but it doesn't matter in such cases.

Comment: HI sorry I cannot find the sparse_z_csrmv.f90 on Intel's website and googled to no avail. Could you point it to me where to find it?

Comment: Please check MKL package: MKLROOT/examples/spblasf/source\ directory

Comment: in the case if you have no such package installed: you may take the mkl package for free from this page (https://software.intel.com/en-us/performance-libraries) or let me know - I will give you this example.

Comment: Hi Huge thanks! i found them in `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281/linux/mkl/examples
`. The file is in`examples_cluster_f.tgz`. Thanks a lot!